# Implementing a move method

Tags: java

I am trying to make a move method to move units, but I'm stuck. Lets say I have a unit at position(3,1), and I want to move it to position(4,1). How do I implement the method? So far I have the code below. (I have a class representing units, but I want the moveUnit in another class (where it is now), that handles these kind of stuff).
Thanks

```
public boolean moveUnit( Position from, Position to ) {

    return false;
}
```

Regarding the Position method, it is used like seen below, where I have a class with testcases using JUnit

```
@Test
public void shouldBePossibleToMoveUnits() {
    Unit u = game.getUnitAt(new Position(2, 0));

    boolean moved = game.moveUnit(new Position(2, 0), new Position(3, 0));
    assertTrue("It should be possible to move units", moved);
    assertNotNull("There should be a unit at 3, 0", u);
}
```

-------------------------------------UPDATE------------------------------

I have written this code to move the unit, but it does not work. Can someone see what I do wrong?

```
Unit unitFrom = ((UnitImpl) getUnitAt(from));

    if(unitFrom == null) { return false; }
    Unit unitTo = ((UnitImpl) getUnitAt(to));

    unitFrom = unitTo;
    unitFrom = null;
```

The unit does not get moved to the new position

Comment: What does the Position object attach to? For example, is there a Player class that has a Position variable? In that case, you would need to pass the Player class and the "to" Position, then modify the Player's Position variable

Comment: should you be passing `int`s as arguments instead of `Position`s, or am I missing something about your `Position` class, if one even exists?

Comment: I feel that the `from` parameter is probably redundant as you should already know  where the unit is prior to this methods invocation .

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how your `Unit` class is set up, this is what you want your method to look like:

```
public boolean moveUnit(Unit unitToMove, Position moveTo) {
    unitToMove.setPosition(moveTo);
    return true;
}
```

This assumes that `Unit` has an internal method to keep track of its position via a `Position` object. You're wanting to move the `Unit`, so you need to pass it as one of the variables.

If you want the `Game` class to internally get the unit, and just have it move a unit at a given position, do this:

```
public boolean moveUnit(Position unitPosition, Position moveTo) {
    Unit unitToMove = getUnitAt(unitPosition);
    if (unitToMove == null) {
        //If no Unit exists at the given position, return false
        return false;
    }
    unitToMove.setPosition(moveTo);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It's basically the setPosition method that I wantto implement in the moveUnit method, and what I am stuck on. But I think I got an idea from what you wrote, gonna give it a try

Answer (score 0):

`Lets say I have a unit at position(3,1), and I want to move it to position(4,1).`

This means you want to end with that unit at (4,1) and no unit at (3,1).

If the unit keeps track of it's position, update that pointer.
If positions keep track of their unit, update those two pointers.

Comment: I have added code in the original post. This might not be a good idea, since it probably would be better than it comes after everyones comments that came before that part of the code. But I can't add code so that it looks nice if I do it as a comment

Comment: This will be very simple once you have variables that represent the state. They were probably given to you in the assignment, but you haven't shown us anything from the surrounding class. Defining a local variable `unitFrom` in your move method is useless. Please consult your textbook or [java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html). If you understand this post, your confusion is almost entirely about basic syntax.